# File works in Java 1.5 but not in Java 7 (java.io.FileNotFoundException Permission Denied)

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, permission-denied

I have a file that I'm trying to access. When I accessed it in Java 1.5 it was fine. I have since upgraded to Java 7 and now I am getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException Permission Denied error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /folder/test.xml (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
at SerializeUtil.write(Unknown Source)
```

It is actually trying to write to the file using an XMLEncoder

```
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename)));
encoder.writeObject(object);
encoder.close();
```

Comment: Is there a process holding a lock on your file?

Comment: And you're absolutely certain that you have permission to write to the  folder?

Comment: what is your filename format ?

Comment: I don't think java api behavior would have changed (after so much of backward compatibility :)) Assuming its exactly the same code on java 5 and java 7, I also think it might be a lock issue.

Comment: Nothing is getting locked as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are under Unix/Linux, try the following command under the user you running java
$ touch /folder/test.xml

If your file is sitting on other locations(for example /home/AAA/folder/test.xml), replace the above path.

The idea is to test if your current user can write the file

Comment: I didn't change users or do anything different.. all I did was change the Java version and rebuild the code

Comment: removing the xml file and letting the application recreate it fixed the issue but still leaves the question why did it work before with java 1.5.

Comment: I guess your java 1.5 app lock the file(for example forget the close statement). so only itself can unlock it. Nothing to do with the version of java